# CentOS DNS not working - Cannot resolve any hostnames

Tags: domain-name-system, centos

I am running Linux VPS on CentOS 6.4, and I log into it remotely via putty

I made a change to my /etc/sysconfig/selinux file:

/etc/sysconfig/selinux

```
# SELINUX= can take one of these three values:
#       enforcing - SELinux security policy is enforced.
#       permissive - SELinux prints warnings instead of enforcing.
#       disabled - No SELinux policy is loaded.
SELINUX=disabled  (default was 'enforcing')
```

So I rebooted my server:

```
shutdown -r now
```

Now it is up and running again, but it cannot resolve any hostnames:

When I do:

```
wget http://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz
```

I get the following error:

```
Resolving www.wordpress.org... failed: Temporary failure in name resolution.
```

Even if I do:

```
nslookup google.com
```

it does not work, same error: cannot resolve hostname.

What is wrong with my server DNS?

Thanks

UPDATE: This is the output from my /etc/resolv.conf file

```
# No nameservers found; try putting DNS servers into your
# ifcfg files in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts like so:
#
# DNS1=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
# DNS2=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
# DOMAIN=lab.foo.com bar.foo.com
```

Also, I can ping IP addresses. So this is a DNS issue

Comment: 1) Have you tried reverting the change you made to IP Tables? 2) Have you checked your DNS settings in /etc/resolv.conf? 3) Have you tried pinging IP addresses (and not hostnames)?

Comment: Put the DNS servers' IP addresses into either your resolv.conf file or your ifcfg-eth<n> file like the resolv.conf file is telling you to.  Are you using NM_Controlled=yes on your ifcfg file?

Comment: Is this your first reboot since setting this server up?  I am guessing it has nothing to do with disabling SELinux and you simply didn't have your DNS settings properly set.  You can try making sure Network Manager is not controlling your DNS by seeing that it is set to NM_Controlled=NO in ifcfg-eth0 and then manually set the DNS and search (domain) settings in resolv.conf, then restart network services.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that the intended audience of this site is professional system administrators operating in a professional capacity. Running your own VPS is more suited to the [unix.se] site. For more information about this site, please [take the tour](http://serverfault.com/about)!

Comment: @Aaron. Thank you for the comment, you may have a point, I did not know that. Anyways, I actually use it to host a few of my smaller clients' websites on it...I am new to linux so I am starting small. This however, still a server...

Comment: @Gregg - Yes, this is my first reboot since I got it.

Comment: RHEL is [extremely well documented](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/). If you intend to manage this server yourself, you would do well to familiarize yourself with the docs as they will be very helpful.

Comment: To all the downvoters - Just note, this is not a Home Server. This is a Server that is rented at an ISP. I use it to administer a webserver, with several websites being hosted on it.By default, the server is secure and I know how to move files within the server to the right places, and to give the right read/write permissions. I just never had any DNS issues before, thus I cam asking here, but I understand this site is for professionals, and I know I am not one

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Simply adding a resolver to `/etc/resolv.conf` will work to configure name resolution, *but might not be persistent*. This is the old way of doing things and assumes your host does not have NetworkManager running. NetworkManager will attempt to manage these files for you, and if you edit them by hand you can find them overwritten. This is likely what happened since the symptom appeared after reboot.

To use this method you will also need to make sure NetworkManager is stopped and disabled.

```
chkconfig NetworkManager off; service NetworkManager stop
```

Or, you can do as the first lines of `/etc/resolv.conf` suggests and configure your name servers in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` (Usually eth0...)

```
DNS1=8.8.8.8
DNS2=8.8.4.4
DOMAIN=localdomain
```

Comment: thank you very much for the help Aaron. People like you make sites like these great, and others learn from it too. One question, do i need to reboot the server when making changes like this?

Comment: I did not reboot and it works. thank you. But do you think it is necessary to reboot?

Comment: @DextrousDave You might want to reboot, just to make sure the machine _can_ reboot properly.

Comment: No it isn't.  If it is working then you should be all set, if not only a restart of network services is necessary with service network restart.  Reboots are rarely needed in Linux unless you modify the kernel version (or a number of other cases).

Comment: thank you Greg. Is it better to use Google DNS servers rather than a local one in your country? What are the benefits of using Google DNS instead, apart from the fact that they are TLD servers?

Comment: The suggestion for Google's DNS is simply that it's free & reliable. YMMV. Feel free to read more about the service [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/).

Answer (score 3):

Based on your reslove.conf file,All content has been commented out with #.
You can add this to your resolve.conf

> nameserver 8.8.8.8
>
> nameserver 8.8.4.4

and save it.
You can replace the google public dns to any dns you want.
try it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the resolv.conf file says the following, so I don't think the DNS settings should be placed in the resolv file...# No nameservers found; try putting DNS servers into your
# ifcfg files in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts like so:

Answer (score 0):

I am sure its your /etc/resolv.conf file.  In your /etc/resolv.conf file add 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 these are for google DNS.  So your file should have the entries listed below.  After that is completed do an nslookup on www.google.com and all should be well.

nameserver 8.8.8.8

nameserver 8.8.4.4

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the resolv.conf file says the following, so I don't think the DNS settings should be placed in the resolv file...# No nameservers found; try putting DNS servers into your
# ifcfg files in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts like so: